# forcing keyboard (not stdin) input in perl despite redirected IO

Tags: perl, posix, stdio

perl, unix (OSX, linux):  is it possible via perl to force a prompt and keyboard user input, even if the user has redirected STDIN and STDOUT?  this is useful to help prevent users from storing passwords.  I know it won't be perfect, but at least it will be helpful.

Comment: Read from `/dev/tty`, but be cautious about annoying people. Remember that not every process has an operational `/dev/tty` (it may be run by `cron`, for example).

Comment: After getting a handle to `/dev/tty`, you can use [`Term::ReadKey`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey) to disable echo and read a line.

Comment: `perl -E 'open (STDOUT, ">", "/dev/tty"); say "ok"' > test.txt` will print to the terminal, and not to the file `test.txt`..

Comment: SSH does just that: even if you redirect STDIN and STDOUT, it's still able to ask you for passwords, passphrases, host authenticity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

thank you, everyone.  here is the working version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub term_interactive {  return -t STDIN && -t STDOUT; }
print "terminal is ".((term_interactive)?"interactive":"batch")."\n";

print "type password : ";

use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode 2; # noecho
open(my $KEYIN, "/dev/tty") or die "cannot open tty for read\n";
print("read ".<$KEYIN>."\n");
close($KEYIN);
ReadMode 0; # restore terminal
## or ReadMode 1; # normal terminal
```

Comment: You should check `STDERR`, too. Even if `STDIN` and `STDOUT` are redirected, `STDERR` often still goes to a terminal.